Rigging the Strap Skirt
I'm trying to rig the gladiator's strap skirt. The idea is to make selected objects follow the belt deformation like it is its stem but also I want to make adjustments afterward and move them independently (or add some constraints for body collisions). So my question is how to make it right? I tried using the bone constraints but no luck.
I considered using cloth physics but I saved it as the last resort because I want to sell this model on stocks and it might be a problem for other people to use only Blender for animation.
The rig is default one from riggify and additional armature for the straps. 

i personally would use cloth modifier with pin group with a very easy geometry and then use mesh deform or lattice to transfer the cloth animation to the complicated geometry.

Thought about it too but is it better for game engines? I mean It will force people to use Blender for animation(I want to sell the model on stocks), right?

please copy that comment to your question so that other people also know, what you want and don't answer in the "wrong direction". Thx for your understanding.

Hello, Sergei.. welcome..  the 'for export'  detail is important, as Chris says, and should be highlighted in your post

Thanks! I added that info in the post.

I figured it out.
First, I created vertex groups on the belt for each strap where they are connected to the belt.
Then I added the Bone constraint Child Of for each root bone of the straps and assigned it to the belt and the corresponding vertex group. Also, I clicked 'Set Inverse' so the axes are not inverted for the bones.
Basically, that's it. Now the root bones of the straps are following the belt deformation. It's a bit clunky but I will fix it with the weight painting.
